# Can I use with android studio webview with ajax function

Tags: php, android, ajax, android-studio

I'm new with android but my questions its how I can use with android studio reload one page normal file HTML
But in this HTML file I created a function .load from another php page with simple echo somtihng.
Its impossible do this?

Comment: [It's same with web page ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20425481/6521116)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In webview you can call javascript code from native java code. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4325639/6521116) for detail.

For a easy way, you can make a js function to do the ajax call when you page loaded. This has nothing to do with android's native code. Just as the plain web applicaiton.